# add an SPListItem from a web part

Tags: sharepoint-server, sandbox-solution, splistitem

I'm using a sandbox solution.
I'm trying to add some items to a list from a button click in my webpart.

It seems easy but with sandbox everything becomes difficult.

I'm getting an exception when I do the `update()`. Here is my code:

```
if(listToLoad != null)
{
SPListItem newItem = listToLoad.Items.Add();
            newItem["Title"] = "test";
            //newItem["FieldTitle"] = web.ServerRelativeUrl;
            try
            {
                //newItem["ContentTypeId"] = spCType.Id.ToString();
                //newItem["FieldUrl"] = web.ServerRelativeUrl;
                //newItem["ParentNewsLetter"] = test["FieldTitle"].ToString();
                //newItem["UserGroupName"] = test["UserGroupName"].ToString();
                /*********Exception occurs here*********/
                newItem.Update();
                listToLoad.Update();

                lbl_message.Text += web.ServerRelativeUrl + "added for parent: " + test["FieldTitle"].ToString() + " and group: " + test["UserGroupName"].ToString() + "<br>";

                foreach (SPWeb _web in web.Webs)
                {
                    LoopThrowSite(_web, test);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
 }
```

Here is the common exception for sandbox.

> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: The sandboxed code execution request was refused because the Sandboxed Code Host Service was too busy to handle the request

I tried another project as a farm solution and it works, so the issue comes from the sandbox solution.
Do you know an alternative to make it work?

Comment: Do other sandboxed solutions work? It might not be an issue with the code.  See if this link helps: http://sharepointknowledgebase.blogspot.com/2014/03/sandboxed-code-execution-request-failed.html#.U8Ze7JRdVy4

Comment: Try by restarting Sandboxed Code Host Service.

Comment: yes it works in farm solution but i don't have access to the farm. Do you know an alternative to use a sandbox solution

Comment: i've restarted sevice: Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Sandboxed Code Service without success. Is it possible to do this in sandboxsolution? else do you have an other solution?

Comment: Try a different _sandboxeded_ solution.  Farm solutions don't run on SPUCWorkerProcess.exe.

Comment: i've tested in an event receiver but still have the error so i suppose it's not possible in sabdbox solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's not allowed to add item in sandbox solution so i developped a client script to complete this action

Answer (score 0):

listToLoad.Update() is not required to add an item. newItem.Update() should be enough.

Comment: ok but my issue is that newItem thow the exception so my item is never added

Comment: Have you set yourspweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true; ?

Comment: yes i've setted to true before with no more success.

Comment: How did you get handle of listToLoad? It has to be SPList listToLoad= yourweb.Lists["ListName"];

Comment: yes i got the list with SPList listToLoad= yourweb.Lists["ListName"]; and i tets if it's not null so it seems to be correct.

Comment: i do an other project in farm solution and it works so the issue comme from sandbox-solution